# Confusing notation for sets of unordered vs ordered pairs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, soft-question, notation, products

Given two finite sets $X$ and $Y$, one may consider the ordered pairs $(x,y)$ with $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$. Then, $(x,y) \not= (y,x)$, and $(x,x)$ exists if $x\in X$ and $x\in Y$.

One may also consider unordered pairs $xy$ with $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$, with $x\ne y$. Then, $\{x,y\}=\{y,x\}$, and $\{x,x\}$ does not exist.

The set of all ordered pairs is denoted by $X\times Y$, and **the set of unordered pairs is often denoted by $X\times Y$ too, which is confusing**.

For instance, in graph theory ordered vs unordered pairs make the distinction between directed and undirected graphs. Therefore, most graph papers dealing with undirected graphs start by saying that they use the ordered pair notations, but consider unordered pairs. In most cases, this is sufficient.

**In some situations, though, one deals with both kinds of pairs jointly and then needs to make a clear distinction.**

It was for instance the case in our paper *[Stream Graphs and Link Streams for the Modeling of Interactions over Time](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.04073)*, where we used the $X\otimes Y$ notation for unordered pairs.

My questions are:

- **is there a standard notation for sets of unordered pairs**? Why not ?
- And **is the $\otimes$ notation appropriate**, although it is already used in various contexts?

A typical example where the distinction is important, although trivial:
$|X\times Y| = |X|\cdot |Y|$, and so $|X\times X| = n^2$ if $|X| = n$. This is different from $$|X\otimes Y| = |(X\setminus Y) \times Y| + |(Y\setminus X) \times X| - |(X\setminus Y)\times(Y\setminus X)| + \frac{|X\cap Y|^2 - |X\cap Y|}{2}$$ leading to $|X\otimes X| = \frac{n \cdot (n-1)}{2}$ if $|X| = n$.

Comment: I would not consider the set of unordered pairs from two sets $X, Y$ meaningful unless $X = Y$, in which case I would write it as ${X \choose 2}$ (assuming we want distinct pairs).

Comment: In fact the usual convention is that $\{x\}=\{x\}$, so that one does not have to bother about repetitions. As to the set of unordered pairs, $X\times X$  is of course a totally wrong notation; $X\otimes X$ is at least different from $X\times X$, but confusing in that it has nothing to do with any other use of $\oplus$.  ${X \choose  2}$ follows the standard convention about cardinality, it is self-explanatory and natural. Also used $X^{(n)}$ for unordered $n$-ples

Comment: Thank you for these interesting comments. Indeed, there cannot be any repetition in an unordered pair, as it is a set, but I saw that some consider $\{x\}$ as a valid unordered pair so I wanted to be precise.

Comment: I like $X\choose 2$, but am disturbed by the fact that it does not generalize to two distinct sets. Also, I am not *that* happy with the combined use of both notations, like, e.g., $T\times {X\choose 2}$. I have similar concerns with $X^{(2)}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The notation "$[X]^2$" for the set of two-element subsets of $X$ is standard at least in logic.

Comment: @Qiaochu writes that he would not consider the set of unordered pairs from two sets $X,Y$ meaningful unless $X = Y$. I would rather say that the notion makes sense precisely when $X$ and $Y$ are both subsets of an ambient superset $T$, so that the intersection $X \cap Y$ is meaningful. But if $X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary sets then I agree that the notion makes little sense. A verbose way of expressing this operation is $\mathrm{Im}(X \times Y \to \binom{T}{2})$. A modest proposal for a notation is $X \, \Box \, Y$ (I am quite convinced no standard notation exists).

Comment: The usual notation is $\mathrm{Sym}^2(X)$, the *second symmetric product* of $X$. It can be seen as the quotient of $X \times X$ by the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action exchanging the two factors.

Comment: If $X \neq Y$, I am not sure that the notion of "unordered pair" really makes sense, because one does not have the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action anymore.

Comment: Ordered pairs (or in general ordered sets) have a set theoretic definition as an unordered set. While the definition is most likely to depend on the purpose, people mostly use ordered pairs to distinguish $(x,y)$ from $(y,x).$ There are multiple ways to define $(x,y)$ so that it has this property, for instance one can define $(x,y) = \{ x, \{x,y \} \}$ (this was actually coined by Kuratowski). The existence of ordered sets can then be verified as a consequence of ZF axioms. So, you can view an ordered set as an unordered set too, if that helps!

Comment: Regarding notations there is some room for confusion unless one is not very clear about them. In context graph theory, I personally feel that contrasting the relationship between ordered and unordered pairs with that between directed and undirected graphs is helpful (assigning an order to a set can be contrasted with assigning a direction to traverse the elements of the set); and so if you are consistent about any specific notations to distinguish directed graphs from undirected ones, you can adopt the same here. I personally write $\vec{G}$ to denote directed graphs in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting comments! It seems that there is no consensus, rather a nice bestiary of relevant notations, each with its own strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: Also, I agree that unordered pairs make sense mostly (if not only) when $X\cap Y \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: You can find some more definitions here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair .

Comment: I see a lot of content here that should have been in answers and not in comments.